# Difference between JavaScript reference type objects and plain objects

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm currently in the learning process of JavaScript. I'm having a confusion with Objects (Reference type and plain objects). Here are some codes that create an object (reference type) :

```
function TheObject(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

TheObject.prototype.theMethod = function() {
  document.write("first : " + this.first + ", last : " + this.last + "</br>");
};

var anObject = new TheObject("Google", "Good");
anObject.theMethod();
```

Here are some other codes which also create an object (is it also reference type?) :

```
var TheAnotherObject = function(first, last){
   return {
     first : first,
     last : last,

     theMethod : function() {
       document.write("first : " + this.first + ", last : " + this.last + "</br>");
     }
   };
 }

 var anotherObject = TheAnotherObject("Yahoo", "Good");
 anotherObject.theMethod();
```

Now, my confusion is where is the actual difference between this two way of creating objects. I know that I can create an Object type in both way (with the "new" keyword). Then what is the difference?

Please help me to understand what point I'm missing here. I know it's very important to understand since JavaScript heavily use functions and objects. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second method doesn't associate a prototype with the `TheObject` class.

Comment: I can sort of guess but don't really know what you mean by "reference type"--where did you see this expression?

Comment: @torazaburo from book "Beginning Javascript" by "Jeremy McPeak". I'm learning from this book.

Comment: This is not standard terminology and frankly is confusing. Although opinions vary on the question of "does JS have classes", it's simplest and most convenient to refer to functions which create objects via `new` as "classes", and then everyone will pretty much know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference is:

1st approach defines `theMethod` method using `prototype`. This means that all `instances` created from that `Class`, will use same definition of that method (`theMethod`)

Otherwise, 2nd approach defines a new `theMethod` method every time a new `instance` is created from that `Class`. Which obviously when having too many instances it is going to be expensive since there will be several definitions for `theMethod` doing the same thing.

Comment: *when having too many instances it is going to be expensive*. Actually, it's not expensive, unless maybe you plan to have millions of instances. We have better things to worry about these days than a few extra bytes of memory. Douglas Crockford promotes this style of programming as I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the creation they are the same.

However the difference is that the first way the method is assigned to the prototype which means there's only one instance of this method.

While in the second example the method of defined for every new object.

So basically the references of theMethod are not the same which means o1.theMethod != o2.theMethod